# Getting issue comments JIRA python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to get all comments of issues created in JIRA of a certain search query. My query is fairly simple:

```
import jira
from jira.client import JIRA

def fetch_tickets_open_yesterday(jira_object):
    # JIRA query to fetch the issues
    open_issues = jira_object.search_issues('project = Support AND issuetype = Incident AND \
    (status = "Open" OR status = "Resolved" OR status = "Waiting For Customer")', maxResults = 100,expand='changelog')

    # returns all open issues
    return open_issues
```

However, if I try to access the comments of tickets created using the following notation, I get a key error.

```
for issue in issues:
    print issue.raw['fields']['comment']
```

If I try to get comments of a single issue like below, I can access the comments:

```
single_issue = jira_object.issue('SUP-136834')
single_issue.raw['fields']['comment']
```

How do I access these comments through search_issues() function?

Comment: Could you specify which JIRA library you're using?

Comment: I am using the python jira library. See below for the import comments that I am running:
    import jira
    from jira.client import JIRA

Answer (score 15):

The comment field is not returned by the search_issues method you have to manually state the fields that must be included by setting the corresponding parameter.

just include the 'fields' and 'json_result' parameter in the search_issue method and set it like this

```
open_issues = jira_object.search_issues('project = Support AND issuetype = Incident AND \
    (status = "Open" OR status = "Resolved" OR status = "Waiting For Customer")', maxResults = 100,expand='changelog',fields = 'comment',json_result ='True')
```

Now you can access the comments without getting keytype error

```
comm=([issue.raw['fields']['comment']['comments'] for issue in open_issues])
```

Answer (score 9):

I struggled with the same issue. Assuming "issue" is an object of type Issue, and "jira" is an object of type JIRA, according to http://jira.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#issues

`issue.fields.comment.comments`

should work, but the fields object does not have any key "comment".

The other option mentioned there works for me:

```
jira.comments(issue)
```

So, for it to work you use the issues from your search result and call jira.comments. E.g.

```
issues =  jira.search_issues(query)
comments = jira.comments(issues[index])
```

(My version of the library is 1.0.3, python 2.7.10)

Comment: use [comment.body for comment in comments] to get the text entered in the comment

Answer (score 8):

```
from jira import JIRA

Jira =  JIRA('https://jira.atlassian.com')

issue_num = "ISSUE-123"

issue = Jira.issue(issue_num)

comments =  issue.fields.comment.comments

for comment in comments:
    print("Comment text : ",comment.body)
    print("Comment author : ",comment.author.displayName)
    print("Comment time : ",comment.created)
```

Comment: This is great although the bit of info I wanted was:

`comment.author.key`

which  I found by printing    `comment.__dict__`