# how to get the number of comments on the issue

Tags: jira

here example

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
def commentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().
getCommentManager()
def numberOfComments = commentManager.getComments(issue).size()
return numberOfComments ? numberOfComments as Double : null
```

but now ComponentManager is deprecated ? and i try:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
def commentManager = ComponentAccessor.commentManager
def numberOfComment = commentManager.getComments(issue).size()
```

but how do I get a specific item to which it is applied?
Simmilary getInstance().

Comment: your variable names are **extremely** weird ... `ComponentManager`s are no *"CommentManager"* s, that doesnt even make any sense and is very misleading ... just saying

Comment: Take a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348346/getting-issue-comments-jira-python

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to access comments :

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
def comments = ComponentAccessor.commentManager.getComments(issue)
if (comments) {

for (item in comments) {
    list.add(item.getBody());
}
return list
}
```